# Laravel: associate two fields on same model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting to do samething with Laravel and I really liked the way the Model is already ready for your query but I've found some problems in this case.

I've created a model for a really simple messaging system:

Fields are:

```
id [int]                  id message
id_user_from [int]        id sender user
id_user_to [int]          id recipient user
cnt [text]                content of message
```

I want to add a relationship between id_user_from and User (standard on Laravel) and also id_user_to (same).

I was able to create a single relation using id_user_from OR id_user_to but not both together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the 2 relationships.

```
public function toUser(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id_user_to');
}

public function fromUser(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id_user_from');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it needs a function with the same name of the related controller (Users).